# WebView not showing on android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-webview

I am trying to get something - anything shown on a webview on android, but I am seeing nothing no matter what I do. The WebView takes up the necessary whitespace, but doesn't show anything, no matter if I hardcode HTML or try to enter a url.

The code for the WebView is:

```
<WebView
      style={{
        width: material.sliderWidth,
        minHeight: 200,
        height: 200,
        marginBottom: 10
      }}
      source={{
        html: "<html><body style='color:red'><h1>Helloworld</h1></body></html>"
      }}
      originWhitelist={['*']}
      scalesPageToFit
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      domStorageEnabled={true}
      mixedContentMode="compatibility"
      onError={syntheticEvent => {
      const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent;
      console.warn('WebView error: ', nativeEvent);
    }}
    />
```

Please see this picture. The whitespace above the bold title is where the image is supposed to be showing:

[image]
Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Did you try giving flex:1 ?

Comment: @ Auticcat, I have tried that, but unfortunately unsuccesfully